# Utf-8 en micropython

Tags: python, utf-8, esp8266, micropython

Existe alguna manera de usar codificación **utf-8** en **Micropython**? Necesito imprimir acentos y alguna eventual letra '**ñ**' en un display LCD 16x2. Desde ya muchas gracias.

***Código en Python:***

```
>>> cadena = 'doña'.encode('utf-8')
>>> cadena
b'do\xc3\xb1a'
>>> cadena.decode('utf-8')
'doña'
>>> cadena2 = 'doña'
>>> cadena2
'doña'
>>>
```

***Código en Micropython:***

```
>>> cadena = 'doña'.encode('utf-8')
>>> cadena
b'do\xc3\xb1a'
>>> cadena.decode('utf-8')
'do\xf1a'
>>> cadena2 = 'doña'
>>> cadena2
'do\xf1a'
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema es de hardware. Un típico display de 16x2 usa un controlador Hitachi HD44780, viene con un limitado juego de caracteres en ROM:

[image: ROM LCD 16x2]

Eso es todo lo que puedes imprimir.

Si quieres imprimir letras con acentos o cualquier otro caracter especial, tendras que definirlos tú mismo. El controlador Hitachi HD44780 te permite redefinir los ocho primeros caracteres de la tabla. Cada caracter se define con una matriz de 5x8 pixeles.

El primer paso es crear un `bytearray` de ocho elementos. Cada valor representa una fila de pixeles. Para ayudarnos, usamos [Character Creator](https://maxpromer.github.io/LCD-Character-Creator/) para dibujar una letra con acento:

[image: Letra á]

que traducido a `bytearray`

```
letra_a = bytearray(2,0,14,2,14,10,14,0)
```

Este arreglo lo tienes que poner en una de las ocho posiciones (0-8) disponbles del controlador:

```
lcd.custom_char(posicion, pixel_map)
letra_a = chr(posicion)
```

y convertir a caracter el valor de la posición. Este "caracter" es la letra a con acento.

Cuando quieras imprimir una "á", tienes que hacerlo en forma independiente (no dentro de una cadena):

```
lcd.putchar(letra_a)
```

Entonces, para imprimir un texto arbitrario, tendrás que hacerlo caracter a caracter, examinando cada uno, y si es uno especial, enviar su representación equivalente.

Comment: Excelente dato lo del display, no había pensado en ello... sí sabía lo de los caracteres custom pero por obvias razones quería evitarlo. Con respecto a las diferencias que se observan entre el codigo ejecutado en Python y el mismo codigo ejecutado en Micropython ( y en eso ya no interviene el display) creo que ya no tiene sentido que intente solucionarlo, al menos no si voy a usar este tipo de display. Me refiero a que el propio lenguaje no me está reconociendo los acentos ni las letras ñ.  Tal vez alguna de las versiones de micropython sí soporte este tipo de caracteres.